Phiflow Visualizations
I am using phiflow visualizations (phi.vis API documentation) and StaggeredGrid. The flow field appears a bit scrunched up, so I attempted to change the size of my figure. However, this only changed the screen behind the graph, not the graph itself. When graphed, it creates a matpltolib screen, but "configure subplots" did not work. If anyone knows how to adjust the size of the graph, thanks :)
plt.style.use("dark_background")
scaled_flow_field = flow_field *0.1
plot(scaled_flow_field, size=(8, 6))
plt.show()

Note:
I scaled the flow field because the default arrow sizes were too large. I am using a dark background for matpltolib.

Is there a particular reason you want to use phi? The same goes with matplot.lib

You are not saying why you want to use phi specifically, but there is a way to do this with matplot.lib that is directly adaptable to your choice. The code below scales whenever the image size is changed.:
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np  

plt.style.use("seaborn")
field_factor = 0.1
flow_field = np.random.rand(10, 10, 2)
scaled_flow_field = flow_field * field_factor


fig_size = (8, 6)
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=fig_size)

X, Y = np.meshgrid(np.arange(flow_field.shape[1]), np.arange(flow_field.shape[0]))
U, V = flow_field[..., 0], flow_field[..., 1]


scale_factor = fig_size[0] * fig_size[1] * field_factor * 3
q = ax.quiver(X, Y, U, V, scale=scale_factor)

plt.show()


Which gives

